# MySQL: Very slow query, not using index, no joins involved

Tags: mysql, index, join

I am running what I think is a very simple query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE m.mbr_nbr
FROM tran.member m
WHERE m.cardnbr = 000099999930
```

The table *member* is a poorly written one, with 133 columns and there are about 2 million rows. The query is being run in a program to gather the mbr_nbr for 20,000 card numbers. So, the query is being run 20,000 times. Is there a better way to handle this or should I try to optimize the query? Maybe by creating an index on the two fields I need?

Rebuilding a better database isn't an option.

Neither field is the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want the following indexes

```
ALTER TABLE tran.member ADD INDEX cardnbr_mbr_nbr_ndx (cardnbr,mbr_nbr);
ALTER TABLE tran.member ADD INDEX mbr_nbr_cardnbr_ndx (mbr_nbr,cardnbr);
```

Then, you could queries like these

Each Member and All Cards for That Member

```
SELECT mbr_nbr MemberNumber,GROUP_CONCAT(cardnbr) Cards
FROM tran.member GROUP BY mbr_nbr;
```

Each Card and All Members Associated with that Card

```
SELECT cardnbr CardNumber,GROUP_CONCAT(mbr_nbr) Members
FROM tran.member GROUP BY cardnbr;
```

So, that the size of `tran.member` does not slow things down, try creating a temp table for the purpose of gathering these two columns

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tran.adhoc_members_cards;
CREATE TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards
SELECT mbr_nbr,cardnbr FROM tran.member WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards ADD INDEX cardnbr_mbr_nbr_ndx (cardnbr,mbr_nbr);
ALTER TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards ADD INDEX mbr_nbr_cardnbr_ndx (mbr_nbr,cardnbr);
ALTER TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO tran.adhoc_members_cards
SELECT mbr_nbr,cardnbr FROM tran.memberl
SELECT mbr_nbr,cardnbr FROM tran.member WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE tran.adhoc_members_cards ENABLE KEYS;
```

Now, you can run the two queries I mentioned like this:

```
SELECT mbr_nbr MemberNumber,GROUP_CONCAT(cardnbr) Cards
FROM tran.adhoc_members_cards GROUP BY mbr_nbr;
SELECT cardnbr CardNumber,GROUP_CONCAT(mbr_nbr) Members
FROM tran.adhoc_members_cards GROUP BY cardnbr;
```

Search for the cardmember you want as well:

```
SELECT cardnbr CardNumber,GROUP_CONCAT(mbr_nbr) Members
FROM tran.adhoc_members_cards WHERE cardnbr = 000099999930;
```